# Do cycle graphs determine groups up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, graph-isomorphism

This erroneous version of the wikipedia article for [Cycle Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cycle_graph_(algebra)&oldid=646136364) stated that the cycle graph of different groups could be the same. The immediate error is that it stated that the cycle graph of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_8$ is the same as $\mathbb Z_{16}$.

My question is, in general, if a group $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic, can they have isomorphic cycle graphs?

Comment: Hold on: Does a *group* even determine a *cycle graph* up to isomorphism? That is, do two primitive generating sets for the same finite group develop cycle graphs that are isomorphic as edge-colored graphs? Has there been a systematic study of these graphs published somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $G$ and $H$ be two non-isomorphic $p$-groups of order $p^a$ and of exponent $p$. (These always exists for $a\geq 3$.)

If I understood the definition correctly, $G$ and $H$ will both have the same cycle graph.

Comment: The smallest examples this yields have order 27. According to http://vixra.org/abs/1406.0183, there are smaller examples, of order 16.

Comment: Yes, I understood. What is an example for order 16?

Comment: Also, could you elaborate? What two p-groups did you have in mind?

Comment: For the examples of order 16, consider $G_{16}^5$ and $G_{16}^6$ in the paper linked above. (I think there's also another pair.) For examples of order $27$, consider $\mathbb{Z}_3^3$ and the non-abelian group of exponent 3 and order 27 (see http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Prime-cube_order_group:U(3,3))