# Is the cycle graph of a group unique?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

I was perusing the [cycle graphs for small groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#List_of_small_non-abelian_groups) on Wikipedia and something bothers me: is the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph_(algebra)) of a finite group actually unique (up to isomorphism)?

For example, if there are any cyclic subgroups of order $5$, the cycle graph is drawn by picking one primitive generating element $a$, and drawing a $5$-cycle in the graph between $e, a, a^2, a^3, a^4$. But a priori, this means the graph will depend on the choice of $a$. Can this result in multiple cycle graphs for the same group? It doesn't seem obvious that these different graphs would be isomorphic in general.

---

**Definition:** A cycle graph of a finite group $G$ is a [simple undirected graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) defined as follows: first, the vertex set of the graph is taken to be the set of elements $g \in G$. Then, for each *maximal* cyclic subgroup of $G$ (cyclic subgroup not fully contained in a larger cyclic subgroup), pick a generator $a$ of the subgroup, and draw undirected edges $e \to a \to a^2 \to a^3 \to \cdots \to a^{k-1} \to a^k = e$ (ignoring any duplicate edges), where $k$ is the order of the subgroup.

My question is whether the cycle graph of $G$ is unique up to isomorphism, regardless of the choices of generator for each maximal cyclic subgroup. Notice that for the purposes of this question, the graph is completely unlabeled -- the original vertex labels (elements of the group) are ignored, and edges are not labeled with the cyclic subgroup they correspond to.

---

Strangely, I can't find a previous thread on this:

- [Do cycle graphs determine groups up to isomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360372/do-cycle-graphs-determine-groups-up-to-isomorphism) asks the converse question of whether the cycle graph uniquely determines the group; Chris Culter asks my question in the comments but is unanswered.
- [How in general does one construct a cycle graph for a group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137319/how-in-general-does-one-construct-a-cycle-graph-for-a-group) asks for how to construct the cycle graph, but the top answer suffers from the same problem that the choice of primitive element for a cycle is not unique.
- I also searched on Google Scholar. I found an interesting paper, [The Cyclic Graph of a Finite Group (Ma, Wei, Zhong)](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/algebra/2013/107265/), but it defines the cycle graph differently, where $x, y$ share an edge if $\langle x, y \rangle$ is cyclic. In this definition the graph is clearly unique. This also seems to me a much more sensible definition, but I don't have an example where Wikipedia's definition actually leads to ambiguity in the resulting graph, up to isomorphism.

Comment: The shape of the graph only depends on lattice structure of the cyclic subgroup lattice and the sizes of the cycles; picking a different generator (a different $a$) will just give you the same cycle, with the same intersections; the only "difference" is in the labels of the vertices... but the labels are not actually part of the graph itself.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, but I'm not sure I follow. I tried some special cases -- if $a$ and $a^2$ generate the same $n$-cycle, suppose we have another element $b$ such that $b^k = a^2$, then choosing $a^2$ instead of $a$ would seemingly change the structure of the graph because it results in a different edge from $b$. In this case, this isn't a problem because it means the cycle for $b$ contains the cycle for $a$. But more generally, why does the graph (yes, ignoring labels, up to isomorphism) not depend on the choice of generator for each cycle?

Comment: Trying to imagine a weirder case -- $a$ generates a $10$-cycle, and $b^2 = a^2$. Well then the cycle for $b$ does not contain the cycle for $a$. So both cycles should be present in the cycle graph. But now, it would seem, choosing $a^7$ as a generator instead of $a$ changes the edge from $b$ to $a^4$ and thus changes the graph...

Comment: If $b^k=a^2$ and both $a$ and $a^2$ generate the same cycle, then there is a power of $b$ that is equal to $a$, for there is a power of $a^2$, say $r$, equal to $a$, so $b^{kr}=a$. Since $r$ must be relatively prime to the order of $a^2$, hence of $b^k$, then $b^{kr}$ has the same order as $b^k$, so it is nontrivial. So the cycle generated by $b$ already had an intersection with $a$.

Comment: In your second example, note that the cycle generated by $b$ intersects the one generated by $a$ in the cycle containing $e,a^2,a^4,a^6,a^8$, and the same powers of $b$ (which must have order 10 as well for this to happen, or else $b$ has order 5 and then $b=a^6$). In terms of the generator $a^7$, it intersects the powers $(a^7)^0, (a^7)^6, (a^7)^2, (a^7)^8, (a^7)^4$, respectively, that is, the same vertices as before: all those with even powers of the generator. So you've switched the labels, but you are intersecting the "same" vertices of the cycle when the dust clears. (contj

Comment: (cont) All you did was take the decagon and "twist" it on the paper. But the graph is not about how you draw it, it's about how the vertices connect. You still have the even-powered vertices of the cycle of $a$ connected to the even-powered vertices of the cycle of $b$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin matching the even powers can still lead to non-isomorphic graphs. When $a,b$ both have order 10 and $a^2=b^2$,     the graph contains $1-a-a^2-b-1$ of length 4. If we use $c:=b^3$ instead of $b$, we have cannot return to 1 with four steps: Two steps starting from 1 on the $a$-cycle or $c$-cycle can take us only to the four *distinct* nodes $a^2, a^{-2}=a^8, c^2= a^6, c^{-2}=a^4$. The graphs are not isomorphic (unless something happening outside these two cyclic subgroups somehow “repairs” this)

Comment: Before going too deep in this, I think it would be helpful to have an actual definition of "the cycle graph". I can't find a precise one the wikipedia page. Is it really just a graph? So only adjacency matters? Or are the edges coloured? Are we taking only maximal cyclic groups? etc I don't think it makes sense to ask a precise like this question unless the definition itself is precise.

Comment: @6005 It doesn't actually matter if the definition you choose  is "standard" or not, but you should at least have a precise definition you are happy with if you want others to be able to answer this question, so please let us know what definition you want to work with.

Comment: @verret Thanks for your suggestion, which is reasonable. I updated the post with a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the isomorphism type of the cycle graph does depend on the choices of generators. Here is an example (inspired by Hagen von Eitzen's comment).
Let $G=C_{10}\times C_2$, with the first factor generated by $a$ and the second generated by $b$. This group has three maximal subgroups, all of order $10$. So the edges of the cycle graph can be decomposed into three $10$-cycles. The five elements in the characteristic subgroup  $H$ of order $5$ are contained in every subgroup of order $10$, so they have valency $6$, while the elements of order $2$ and $10$ are contained in a unique subgroup of order $10$, so they have valency $2$.

Now, for some choices of generators, for example $\{a,ab,a^6b\}$, elements of $H$ have exactly two elements at distance $2$, which happen to be in $H$, and there are three $2$-paths between them, as in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GroupDiagramMiniC2C10.png

For some other choices of generators, for example $\{a,ab,a^2b\}$, this is not the case. (In this case, there are four vertices at distance $2$, some with a unique path, some with two paths.)

Comment: Doesn't $C_{10} \times C_2$ only have three maximal subgroups? All of order 10. Only order-2 elements are $(0, 1)$, $(5, 0)$, and $(5, 1)$, which are contained in the order-10 subgroups generated by $(2, 1)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(1, 1)$, respectively.

Comment: The graph in question is drawn (at least in one way) on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GroupDiagramMiniC2C10.png), with three order-10 cycles. It doesn't have any odd-degree vertices.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake, should be ok now.

Comment: Very nice! Minor gripe: since the vertices are unlabeled, "elements at distance 2" is ambiguous. An alternative argument is that for $\{a, ab, a^6 b\}$ the graph has diameter 5, whereas for $\{a, ab, a^2 b\}$ it has diameter 4.

Comment: I added a drawing of the two graphs as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here are drawings of the graphs that are discussed in verret's answer.
Both of these are valid "cycle graphs" for the abelian group $C_{10} \times C_2$, otherwise known as $C_5 \times C_2 \times C_2$ or, as an additive group,
$$
(\mathbb{Z}\;/\;5\mathbb{Z})
\times (\mathbb{Z}\;/\;2\mathbb{Z})
\times (\mathbb{Z}\;/\;2\mathbb{Z})
$$

The red elements are the central subgroup $\{(a, 0, 0) \;\mid\; a \in \mathbb{Z} \;/\; 5\mathbb{Z}\}$, which is equal to the intersection of all three maximal subgroups. The identity element is unlabeled, but assume it is at the top. First, using generators $(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)$, we have that all three generators double to get $(2, 0, 0)$, so we have the following graph:

[image]

Alternatively, using generators $(1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 1)$, the first two generators double to get $(2, 0, 0)$ but the third doubles to get $(4, 0, 0)$ instead. We end up with the following graph:

[image]

Finally, the graphs are non-isomorphic because the first graph has [diameter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) 5, while the second has diameter 4.